# Only get String from hasOne Relation

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have two models:

a) Recipe
b) User

Each Recipe hasOne User. When (REST) requesting a Recipe, I want also get the name of the related User in my JSON answer, like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "name": "Recipe Name",
  "description": "Description goes here",
  "userName": "Testuser"
}
```

What I get instead is:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user_id": 1,
  "name": "Recipe Name",
  "description": "Description goes here",
  "userName": "Testuser",
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Testuser",
    "email": "mail@example.com"
  }
}
```

This is my function in the RecipeController:

```
public function show($id) {
    $recipe = Recipe::find($id);
    $recipe->userName = (string) $recipe->user->name;

    return $recipe;
}
```

My Recipe Model has the following attribute with a getter:

```
protected $userName = null;

public function setUserName($userName) {
    $this->userName = $userName;
}
```

What is interesting is the fact, that when using this code snipet, I also get the whole User Object as JSON string as part of the Recipe JSON string:

```
public function show($id) {
    recipe = Recipe::find($id);
    $recipe->user->name;

    return $recipe;
}
```

So there is some magic happening in the call of my User Object, belonging to the Recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add your relationships method name to your `$hidden` property array inside your `Recipe` model to remove it from json results.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

```
class Recipe extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = ['user'];

    /**
     * The appended attributes shown in JSON results.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = ['username'];

    /**
     * The username attribute accessor for JSON results.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public function getUsernameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->user->name;
    }
}
```

I don't believe there's a way to perform this dynamically besides forming your own set of JSON results.

You could also add the `$hidden` property to your `User` model to remove user attributes you want hidden from JSON results? This would allow you to utilize the serialized relationship model without returning sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks! This works for the specific situation, but sometimes I need the whole User Object in my Recipe model. What would be the best way to accomplish it "on demand"?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this happen because you access the User relation. By default, Eloquent implements the Lazy Loading, but, when you access the User relation to get the name, the entire object is loaded and attached to your Recipe object.

To hide the relation on your json, you should add the property to the $hidden property on your model

```
protected $hidden = ['user'];
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. As soon, as I invoke the access to the username the whole User Object is attached to the JSON string, regardless if I set it to null after extracting the String.